# Import javascript into html on play 2.0 framework

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm having problems including local javascript files into my html that is on the play  framework. The paths are correct and I even tried including the javascript file in the same directory. However, imports from the web (the main libraries i'm using) work just fine.

```
@(execId: String)

<html>

<head>
<title>Timeline</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript"

src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "../../public/javascripts/profilesJS/stack.js">  </script>


</head>


<body>
<input id="profiles" type="button" value="Profiles" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        alert(tester());
    </script>

</body>


</html>
```

the javascript file simply looks likes this

```
function tester(){

return "test";

}
```

And the error i get is:

```
tester is not defined
```

at the line with the alert

Comment: We don't know what did you try. Show some sample to allow us help you.

Comment: i added in my code and the error i was getting (testing with firebug)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [assets documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/Assets) (and routing in general) you need to use the reverse routing in your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/profilesJS/stack.js")'></script>
```

it builds the correct `src` path to your `/public/javascripts/profilesJS/stack.js` file (by default routing config it will be `/assets/javascripts/profilesJS/stack.js`)